# Python matplotlib - updating data during animation in Conway's Game of Life

Tags: python, matplotlib

The code below creates an animation for Conway's Game of Life using Python and matplotlib.

I am not sure why I have to do:

```
grid = newGrid.copy()
mat.set_data(grid)
```

Instead of simply:

```
mat.set_data(newGrid)
```

How can I update the array associated with the plot, without the above copying?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import matplotlib.animation as animation

N = 100
ON = 255
OFF = 0
vals = [ON, OFF]

# populate grid with random on/off - more off than on
grid = np.random.choice(vals, N*N, p=[0.2, 0.8]).reshape(N, N)

def update(data):
  global grid
  newGrid = grid.copy()
  for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
      total = (grid[i, (j-1)%N] + grid[i, (j+1)%N] + 
               grid[(i-1)%N, j] + grid[(i+1)%N, j] + 
               grid[(i-1)%N, (j-1)%N] + grid[(i-1)%N, (j+1)%N] + 
               grid[(i+1)%N, (j-1)%N] + grid[(i+1)%N, (j+1)%N])/255

      if grid[i, j]  == ON:
        if (total < 2) or (total > 3):
          newGrid[i, j] = OFF
      else:
        if total == 3:
          newGrid[i, j] = ON

  grid = newGrid.copy()
  mat.set_data(grid)
  return mat 

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
mat = ax.matshow(grid)
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, interval=50,
                              save_count=50)
plt.show()
```

The output seems correct - I can see gliders, and other expected patterns:

[image: Conway's Game of Life using Python/matplotlib]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no particular reason why `mat.set_data()` needs a copy of `newGrid` - the important thing is that the global `grid` gets updated from iteration to iteration:

```
def update(data):
  global grid
  newGrid = grid.copy()

  """
  do your updating. this needs to be done on a copy of 'grid' because you are
  updating element-by-element, and updates to previous rows/columns will
  affect the result at 'grid[i,j]' if you don't use a copy
  """

  # you do need to update the global 'grid' otherwise the simulation will
  # not progress, but there's no need to copy()
  mat.set_data(newGrid)
  grid = newGrid

  # # there's no reason why you couldn't do it in the opposite order
  # grid = newGrid
  # mat.set_data(grid)

  # at least in my version of matplotlib (1.2.1), the animation function must
  # return an iterable containing the updated artists, i.e. 'mat,' or '[mat]',
  # not 'mat'
  return [mat]
```

Also, in `FuncAnimation` I'd recommend passing `blit=True` so that you're not redrawing the background on every frame.